# Insert value in blank cell if values in two other columns equal

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

trying to get a script to work on google sheets and having trouble getting the second requirement to work. I found the script from multiple places and put them together to what it is now but perhaps I am not understanding it enough to be able to tweak it properly. What I would like it to do is to look at two different columns(fruit and status) and if they have a particular value, input a value into another column. Here is the current script:

```
function myFunction() {
var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var sheetName = activeSheet.getSheetName();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var fruit = sheet.getRange('a2:a').getValues();
var cost = sheet.getRange('c2:c').getValues();
var status = sheet.getRange('b2:b').getValues();
 for (var row in fruit)
  for (var col in fruit[row])
   if (fruit[row][0] == 'Apple' && status[row][0] == 'Ripe' ) {
    num = parseInt(row) + 1;
    sheet.getRange('c' + num).setValue('5.5');
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
function yourFunction(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();//columns are fruit,status and then cost.
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(vA[i][0].toString().toLowerCase()=='apple' && vA[i][1].toString().toLowerCase()=='ripe'){
      vA[i][2]=5.5;//write back into array and write all of them at one time after loop.
    }
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);//This writes all of the data at one time.
}
```

This is what my spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

Comment: Hmm. This doesn't seem to do anything. Here is a link to a google sheet that I am using as a test case. Can you see if you can make it work here? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FrRzq1IDn1OG2QJHzAFg9JpCsIUQGHcqgWm_IIt-BqM/edit#gid=0

Comment: Sorry spoke too soon. This worked however I had to remove the toLowerCase() functions to get it to work. Not really sure how that plays a role in here but was the reason it wasn't working at first. Thanks for the tips!